# php Multidimensional Array for key and get value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following code sample:

```
$arr = array(
  array(
    'packid'=> '1', 'total' => '30'),
  array(
    'packid'=> '2', 'total' => '20')
);
```

$arr is in a loop

```
 foreach ($pack->memberPack as $memPack) {
            if($memPack->packId = $search_arr_key)
            //get the `total` value then do something
        }
```

and $memPack object like this:

```
array(1) {
["memberPack"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(MemberPack)#290 (6) {
    ["errors"]=>
    NULL
    ["attributes":"ActiveRecord\Model":private]=>
    array(3) {
      ["memberPackId"]=>
      int(1)
      ["packId"]=>
      int(1)
      ["memberId"]=>
      int(14369)
    }  
  }
}
```

}

How can i search the key `packId` equal to `$memPack->packId` and get the match total? (ex. if `packId =2` and get the value 20 )

Comment: Do you mean besides a loop?

Comment: updated the question, the $arr is in a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better performance, here is a good implementation.

```
$array = array_combine(array_column($arr, 'packId'), array_column($arr, 'total'));
$total = $array[$memPack->packId];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a loop that finds the result according to the packid you select.

```
<?php

$arr = array(
  array(
    'packid'=> '1', 'total' => '30'),
  array(
    'packid'=> '2', 'total' => '20')
);

$whateverPackidYouWant = 2;
$answer;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {

if ($arr[$i]['packid'] == $whateverPackidYouWant) {
   $answer = $arr[$i]['total'];
}

}

echo $answer;

?>
```

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate the array and check if the subarray contains the matching `packid` and `total` items. Break the loop on the first match:

```
$packid = 2;

foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
  if ($v['packid'] == $packid && isset($v['total'])) {
    $total = $v['total'];
    break;
  }
}
```

Another approach (less optimal, but may look elegant to some people):

```
$key = array_search($packid, array_column($arr, 'packid'));
if ($key !== false && isset($arr[$key]['total'])) {
  $total = $arr[$key]['total'];
}
```

where `array_column` builds an array from the `packid` values (`[1, 2]`) in the order that matches the order of subarrays in `$arr`; `array_search` returns the index of the first occurrence of `$packid` in the array of `packid` values (and thus, the key of the subarray in `$arr`). The rest of the code fetches the `total`.

I have added this example for completeness. Don't use it as it is suboptimal.

Comment: THX, but I wonder why the second approach is less optimal ? can see some statistical number?

Comment: @DoranWu, `array_column` builds an array from _all_ the items in `$arr` (`O(n)`). Then `array_search`, in worst case, iterates all the items in the generated array (`O(n)`). Thus, in the worst case it is a `O(2n)` operation. And the first approach (`foreach`) breaks the loop on the first match which is `O(n)` in worst case. Besides, the code with `array_search` and `array_column` is less readable, and even less flexible